# Create an array of countries and display them in a select box

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am new in Rails and I am trying to put countries in array and then display them in a select box. My array looks like this:

```
country = {}
country['FR'] = 'France'
country['UK'] = 'United Kingdom'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your view, do the following :

```
<%= select_tag 'countries', 
            options_for_select(@countries.to_a) %>
```

The `@countries.to_a` will transform your hash into a array.
If your hash is the following :

```
{'France' => 'FR', 'United Kingdom' => 'UK'}
```

After, after `to_a` you'll have the following array :

```
[['France', 'FR'], ['United Kingdom', 'UK']]
```

The `options_for_select`  method takes an array and create the options tags.
When the entry of the array is an array itself, the first entry (France or United Kingdom here) is the value. And the second one is the key (FR or UK here).

The `select_tag` function creates a select tag.

Comment: Thank you: after setting @countries = {'France' => 'FR', 'United Kingdom' => 'UK'} it works

Comment: Oh indeed my bad. It's the opposite. The first is the value and then comes the id.